# Как избавиться от ошибки Assignments to the 'variable' from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как избавиться от предупреждения:

*Assignments to the 'torrentFile' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect*

(На всякий случай перевод:
*Присваивания переменной torrentFile из React Hook useEffect будут теряться после каждого рендеринга. Чтобы сохранить значение с течением времени, сохраните его в хуке useRef и сохраните изменяемое значение в свойстве .current. В противном случае вы можете переместить эту переменную прямо в useEffect*)

Если так вроде и должно быть, что переменная не сохраняет свое значение и при повторном вызове может меняться на другое запрашиваемое значение.

Вот пример кода, один из нескольких, где выводится такое предупреждение

```
    useEffect(() => {

            setVideoId(videoId = match.params.videoId)

            fetch('/api/...', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({"videoID": videoId})
            });


            fetch('/api/...' + videoId)
                .then((res) => {console.log(res);
                    return(res.json())
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    setVideoData(videoData= res);
                    console.log(videoData)
                    fetch(res.torrentURL)
                        .then(res => res.blob())
                        .then(res => {
                            setTorrentFile(torrentFile= res)
                        })

                    fetch('/api/...')
                        .then((res3) => {
                            return (res3.json())
                        })
                        .then(res3 => {
                            setUserData(userData= res3, !isFetching);
                            setIsFetching(false);
                        })
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                    setError(isFetching, error = e );
                })
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предупреждении хука useEffect - Assignments to the 'variable-name' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025271/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%85%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-useeffect-assignments-to-the-variable-name-variable-from)

Comment: Не уверен, что на той ссылке абсолютно аналогичная проблема, но возможно я не особо разобрался в этом вопросе, если кто-то сможет объяснить, почему это так работает и не считается правильным, буду очень сильно благодарен

Comment: Покажи код setTorrentFile()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, вместо `setTorrentFile(torrentFile= res)` нужно `setTorrentFile(res)`.